# How to securely controlling data without keeping it in postmeta?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, post-meta, wpdb

I'm looking for another alternative instead of keeping the data in the post metain the post like plugin I developed for wordpress. I want to save the likes of the posts to a database and then show it to users. I think it is not safe to keep in postmeta thats why i asked for. Thank you for your help.

Here is my plugin code:

```
<?php
//Builds admin panel page for LikeMyPost
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_menu' );

//Add LikeMyPost tab under posts menu
function admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Like My Post Dashboard', 'Like My Post', 'activate_plugins', 'likemypost_admin', 'admin_panel');
}

function admin_panel() {
    if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {                                    //CHECK IF USER ADMIN OR NOT
        wp_die(__( 'You are not allowed to inspect content of this page.'));        //IF NOT THEN SHOW AN ERROR MESSAGE
    }
?>


    <div class="wrap" style="font-size: 15px; text-align:center;">
        <h3 style="color: #00BFFF; font-size: 30px;"> =Like My Post - Mostly Liked Tags= </h3>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;" > Most liked tags are listed by descending order. You can easily monitor them from this page. </p>

        <?php

        //Using Wordpress Database Class
        global $wpdb;

        //BUILDING PAGES (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)
        $counter = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT terms.term_id)
                          FROM $wpdb->terms AS terms, 
                          $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS taxonomy, 
                          $wpdb->term_relationships AS relationships, 
                          $wpdb->postmeta AS postmeta
                          WHERE terms.term_id = taxonomy.term_id
                                AND taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                                AND relationships.term_taxonomy_id = terms.term_id
                                AND postmeta.post_id = relationships.object_id
                                AND postmeta.meta_key = '_likes_count'";

        $tags = $wpdb->get_var($counter);
        $tag_limit_per_page = 10;
        $page_number = ceil($tags / $tag_limit_per_page);
        $page = isset($_GET['pages']) ? (int) $_GET['pages'] : 1;

        if ($page < 1) {
            $page = 1;
        } else if ($page > $page_number) {
            $page = $page_number;
        }

        $limiter = ($page - 1) * $tag_limit_per_page;
        $current_page = add_query_arg(NULL, NULL);
        ?>

        <table class="widefat fixed" style="text-align: center;">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                <th style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>ID number of tag</th>
                <th style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>Tag Names</th>
                <th style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>Total Number Of Posts</th>
                <th style='font-weight: bold;text-align: center;'>Likes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
            // LISTING TAGS
            $SQLquery = "SELECT A.term_id AS tag_id, A.name, B.count, SUM(C.meta_value) AS like_count
                    FROM $wpdb->terms AS A, $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS B, $wpdb->term_relationships AS P, $wpdb->postmeta AS C
                    WHERE A.term_id = B.term_id
                          AND B.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                          AND P.term_taxonomy_id = A.term_id
                          AND C.post_id = P.object_id
                          AND C.meta_key = '_likes_count'
                    GROUP BY A.term_id, A.name, B.count
                    ORDER BY like_count DESC
                    LIMIT $limiter, $tag_limit_per_page";    //1-10, 10-20 gibi listeleme

            $tags = $wpdb->get_results($SQLquery, OBJECT);
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> $tag->tag_id </td>";
                echo "<td> <a href='".get_tag_link($tag->tag_id)."'> $tag->name </a> </td>";
                echo "<td> $tag->count </td>";
                echo "<td> $tag->like_count </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <?php
        //SELECTING PAGES FROM FOOTER
        for($i = 1; $i <= $page_number; $i++) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                echo $i.' ';
            } else {
               echo '<a href="'.$current_page.'&pages=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>  
<?php 
}
```

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT A.term_id AS tag_id, A.name, SUM(D.meta_value) AS like_count     /*tableName.columName*/
                FROM $wpdb->terms AS A, 
                $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS B, 
                $wpdb->term_relationships AS C,
                 $wpdb->postmeta AS D
                WHERE A.term_id = B.term_id
                  AND B.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                  AND C.term_taxonomy_id = A.term_id
                  AND D.post_id = C.object_id
                  AND D.meta_key = '_likes_count'
                GROUP BY A.term_id, A.name
                ORDER BY like_count DESC
                LIMIT $limiter, $maxTag";           //From 0 to $limit value
```

Comment: May I ask what's wrong with postmeta? What do you mean by "is not safe to keep in postmeta"?

Comment: Im asking, how can i check if user liked or not ? Can i do this with postmeta ?

Comment: It's not simple but maybe you want to create your own database table for your plugin, there's an example of doing this here. Then you could save all the likes for each post in a table. There's a lot to learn here though: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-database-tables-for-plugins/